# How to choose the best model for Non Negative Matrix Factorization?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I am applying NMF with NMF R package. In the early stages, I'm comparing three algorithms (Lee, Brunet,nsNMF) visualizing how fast they converge and how much they reduce residues as in the image down below:

I would choose brunet algorithm to avoid any excessive reduction of  residues. How would you choose?[image: Algorithms]

Comment: The reconstruction error is a good criterion for analyzing the convergence behavior of NMF algorithms. However, in practice, the analysis of the factors is the most important. NMF is an ill-posed problem, the factorization of a given data matrix may produce infinite equivalent solutions. Each solution minimizes the error, but few of them are meaningfull.

Comment: In the figure, the three algorithms converge almost at the same speed, but it's clear that nsNMF gives the lowest error, which is better. To evaluate which model is better, you should analyze the results obtained in a real case, measure how good the results are, and compare based on some criteria.